# ctrl click not working for python project pydeveditor

Tags: python, eclipse

I am using eclipse for python and my ctrl+click is not working ?  I have already add pyDevEditer and it is active in Hyperlinking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Close the class you are working on.
2. Press "Control+Shift+T"
3. Search with class name
4. Open the class Now "Ctrl+Click" should work

Comment: Question has been already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840701/eclipse-ctrl-click-hyperlink-not-working/45960153). Please try some of the answers there.